# Split text according to size of stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

On a windows store app project, i have 2 StackPanels one with 200x200 and another with 200x500 and a scrollviewer inside it(just the second one), i also have a string with some text.

what i want is to split the string so that i get 2 strings, and the first one fits on the 200x200 area, and the rest will go to the second stackapanel with the scrollviewer.

How can i split a string according to the dimensions?

i tried using some functions like this one but dindt quite get it.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
        textBox1.Width = size.Width;
        textBox1.Height = size.Height;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`FormattedText` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx). `TextRenderer` is for WinForms, not WPF.

You can find sample implementation here: [WPF equivalent to TextRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840642/293099). You may need to asjust code to apply [width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.maxtextwidth.aspx) and [height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.maxtextheight.aspx) of the box.

There're also methods for WinRT: [How can I calculate the width of a string in Metro (without displaying it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126076/how-can-i-calculate-the-width-of-a-string-in-metro-without-displaying-it), but they depend on creating a `TextBlock` which isn't rendered.

Comment: Oops, it's WinRT. Updated answer.